# Optaplanner strange behaviour when FULL_ASSERT

Tags: optaplanner

I am developing an incremental solver for rostering, the two planning entities are Assignment and Employee, worker has an @InverseRelationShadowVariable collection of assignments.
I have noticed a strange behaviour when using FULL_ASSERT.

At the start of the LS phase an EmployeeSwapMove is evaluated.

After that the listener is invoked which first retracts all assignments from Employee than inserts all assignments as per the move to the shadowed collection.

After that resetWorkingSolution is invoked, but the Employee has the Assignments before the move.

Optaplanner also logs, that the above move has been selected, but the Employee state (shadow collection) does not reflect that.

After that the score gets corrupted, of course.

The issue is not there when using FAST_ASSERT.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Try running `NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT`. Does the corruption reproduce?

Comment: I fixed it before reading the comment (see my answer). But thanks, I never knew there was such an ASSERT type.

Answer (score 2):

I found out at last. In my Listener I messed up the after/beforeVariableChanged calls.